# load text file in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, uiwebview

I am having a problem with loading a text file with Japanese characters that is saved with ANSI format.

The problem is that I cannot seem to encode the file content correctly. The closest thing I got was when I used the following code to read the file content:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: self.filePath encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error: &error];
```

while it did result in some japanese characters, they were wrong. I tried using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but that gives a `nil` NSString.

Now I know it can be done since I uploaded the file to Google Drive and the Google Drive app was able to display it correctly.

Can someone explain how such a thing can be achieved? Please note that since my application is actually a file browser, the content of the file to view can be written in any language and saved in any encoding.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First thing check whether file path exist or not. Second thing did you try encoding using NSASCIIStringEncoding inspite of NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: Aww so sad  can you paste your file data here which you are reading??